# Jquery prependTo adds display:block

Tags: jquery, css, prepend

Cant seem to find the answer to this.

My code looks like this:

```
var new_img = '<img id="' + drag_id + '" rel="' + drop_id + '" class="' + gallery_link + ' drop_out" src="' + drag_src + '" />';

var drop_img = '<div id="' + ($(ui.draggable).attr("id")) + '" class="not-droppable" rel="' + drop_id + '">' + new_img + '</div>';

$(drop_img).hide().prependTo('li[id=' + drop_id + ']').fadeIn(2000);
```

When the `div` with the image inside it is prepended to the `LI` it adds `style:display-block` to the `div`. How do I make it so that the prepended `div` does not add the `style` element as the `class` for this element is `display: inline-block`?

I have tried setting the `style` element on the `div` tag above to `display: inline-block`; however, this then gets changed to `display: block`. If I try and set the CSS `display: inline-block` in the stylesheet to `!important` the `div`, `style` becomes `display-none`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(drop_img)
    .css('display','none')
    .prependTo('li[id=' + drop_id + ']')
    .fadeIn(2000);
```

[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) works on element that already in DOM.